# Excel crashes if I run subroutine on entire file but works fine in segments

Tags: vba, excel, crash

I've written a subroutine in VBA to insert images into a spreadsheet by product sku (the images are named by sku). I've done as much error handling as I can think of and the code works fine in small batches (including the error handling); but when I run this on the entire spreadsheet (2400 lines), it crashes every time it hits a sku where the image doesn't exist, even though these instances are handled correctly if I go through the debugger.
My first thought was that it was just too much for Excel to handle so I tried to add a pause in (maybe a long shot) - this didn't work.

I've pasted the code below - anyone come across this before?

To explain the code further, next to the sku column there are some associated products so the idea is that if the main image doesn't exist, we can loop through the associated products and try to use one of those - if there still aren't any matching images then the main sku should be stored in an array and then placed on a new sheet for reference at the end of the subroutine - all works perfectly when debugging, but crashes when run on the whole file.

```
Sub InsertPic()
Dim MySht As Worksheet
Dim MyPic As Shape
Dim MyLeft As Single, MyTop As Single
Dim noImage() As String
Dim noImageSheet As Worksheet

'stop screen updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

masterSpreadsheet = ActiveSheet.Name

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
'define first part of noImage array
k = 0


Set MySht = ActiveSheet

For i = 2 To lastRow

    'save every 100 images
    shouldISave = i Mod 100

    If shouldISave = 0 Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
    End If

    'If i Mod 50 = 0 Then
    '    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
    'End If


    MyTop = Rows(Cells(i, 1).Row).Top + 1
    MyLeft = Columns(Cells(i, 1).Column).Left + 1


    'turn off error checking
    On Error Resume Next

    'try to define image based on main sku
    Set MyPic = MySht.Shapes.AddPicture("W:\Design on 'Pmcsbs' (Y)\Brochure\" & Cells(i, 2) & ".jpg", _
                msoFalse, msoTrue, MyLeft, MyTop, -1, -1)

    'use fallback images from associated products
    'check if MyPic is set
    If MyPic Is Nothing Then
        'Split associated products into array
        scndImage = Split(Cells(i, 3), ",")
        'check that array is not empty
        On Error Resume Next
        isItEmpty = scndImage(0)

        If Len(isItEmpty) > 0 Then
            j = 0
            'loop through array while picture isn't set
            Do While MyPic Is Nothing
                'try to set the picture with each assoc product code
                Set MyPic = MySht.Shapes.AddPicture("W:\Design on 'Pmcsbs' (Y)\Brochure\" & scndImage(j) & ".jpg", _
                    msoFalse, msoTrue, MyLeft, MyTop, -1, -1)
                j = j + 1
                'stop the loop when we reach the upper limit of the array
                If j = UBound(scndImage) + 1 Then
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
        End If
    End If

    'check if picture still doesn't exist after all codes have been tried
    If MyPic Is Nothing Then
        ReDim Preserve noImage(k) As String
        noImage(k) = Cells(i, 2)
        k = k + 1
    End If

    'turn error checking back on
    On Error GoTo 0

    'only run the below if MyPic exists
    If Not MyPic Is Nothing Then
    ' now resize pic
        MyPic.Height = Cells(i, 1).Height - 2

        If MyPic.Width > Cells(i, 1).Width Then
            MyPic.Width = Cells(i, 1).Width
        End If
    End If

    Set MyPic = Nothing

Next

    'if noImage has data in then print that to a new sheet
    On Error Resume Next
    isItEmpty2 = noImage(0)

    noImgLastRow = 1

    If Len(isItEmpty2) > 0 Then
        'check if no image sheet exists and get lastRow if it does
        On Error Resume Next
        Set noImageSheet = Sheets("No Images")
        On Error GoTo 0

        'if it doesn't exist create it
        If noImageSheet Is Nothing Then
            Sheets.Add.Name = "No Images"
            'if it does, update the last row number
        Else
            noImgLastRow = noImageSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        End If

        m = 1
        For l = 0 To UBound(noImage)
            Sheets("No Images").Cells(noImgLastRow, 1) = noImage(l)
            m = m + 1
            noImgLastRow = noImgLastRow + 1
        Next
    End If

    Sheets(masterSpreadsheet).Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Save

    'email Jack to confirm it has completed
    Call Mail_images_spreadsheet_finished

    'Update screen again
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of using `On Error Resume Next` and then trying to load a picture which might not exist, it would be better to use `Dir(pathToFileHere)` to check for the file, and only load it if it exists.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't had chance to fully review this code (a lot of what I do is to complete a one-time task quickly) but the `Dir` function has proved really useful for other tasks and saved a lot of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling error checking needs to be reset - these instructions come in pairs. In your code, you disable EC twice for each row but only enable it again once. This leads to memory consumptions which builds up and eventually crashes Excel.
I propose the following changes:

```
    ' turn off error checking
    On Error Resume Next
    'try to define image based on main sku
    Set MyPic = MySht.Shapes.AddPicture("W:\Design on 'Pmcsbs' (Y)\Brochure\" & Cells(i, 2) & ".jpg", _
                msoFalse, msoTrue, MyLeft, MyTop, -1, -1)
    On Error GoTo 0  ' <~~ reset EC
    ...
```

and again here:

```
        On Error Resume Next
        isItEmpty = scndImage(0)
        ' many many lines of code following
        ...
    'turn error checking back on
    On Error GoTo 0
```

change to:

```
        On Error Resume Next
        isItEmpty = scndImage(0)
        'turn error checking back on
        On Error GoTo 0  ' <~~
        ' many many lines of code following
        ...
```

and

```
'if noImage has data in then print that to a new sheet
On Error Resume Next
isItEmpty2 = noImage(0)
On Error Goto 0  ' <~~
```

Then, your code still contains a commonly seen bug when using `On Error Resume Next`. If you have

```
On Error Resume Next
set testvar = myarray(indx)
On Error Goto 0
if testvar is Nothing then ' element does not exist
```

then the `set testvar` statement will be skipped if the array element doesn't exist. Assume that the test is positive and `testvar` is set; if the test fails in the next loop iteration `if testvar is Nothing` will be False although the assignment failed. You have to reset the `testvar` before trying the assignment!

```
set testvar = Nothing  ' <~~ !!!
On Error Resume Next
set testvar = myarray(indx)
On Error Goto 0
if testvar is Nothing then ' element does not exist
```

In your code this affects `MyPic` and `isItEmpty` and `isItEmpty2`.

Comment: Thanks for your thoroughness; a good few lessons learned here. I haven't had chance to fully review this code but it's been useful to prevent these mistakes occurring in more recent projects.